# Do SQL scripts executed by other SQL scripts inherit the system variables set in the parent for all clients?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

## Background

We are using Oracle 12c.

I have a PL/SQL file called *load_all.sql* which executes another PL/SQL file
called*financial_aid.sql*.  The developers are adding ampersand characters to comments in the *financial_aid.sql*.  When they compile *financial_aid.sql* in PL/SQL Developer the ampersands do not register as Oracle SQL substitution variables.  However, when it's executed via an ant script they do register as SQL substitution variables.  As a result, we get the package fails to create the package body and displays the following error

```
SP2-0546: User requested Interrupt or EOF detected.
```

## Proposed Solution

To resolve this we want to add a system variable `SET DEFINE OFF` to the SQL files. This prevents the the  `SP2-0546` error from occurring during out automated build process.

However, our build process is complex and uses many different clients ( ANT, SQLPlus, Maven, etc ) to run these PL/SQL files.  Additionally, *load_all.sql* dynamically executes hundreds of other SQL files and we don't want to have to `SET DEFINE OFF` in all these files.

## Question

We know that `SET DEFINE OFF` is a client side system variable.  If we add `SET DEFINE OFF` to *load_all.sql* will **every** file executed by the *load_all.sql* parent inherit the `DEFINE OFF` parameter for **all** clients, or is the function client specific?

Below is an example of *load_all.sql* with the `SET DEFINE OFF` variable for clarification

## Code

```
SET DEFINE OFF
PROMPT 'loading @financial_aid.sql'
@financial_aid.sql
PROMPT 'loading @other_file.sql'
@other_file.sql
PROMPT 'loading @other_file2.sql'
@other_file2.sql
```

**We essentially want to know if financial_aid.sql, other_file.sql, and all the other sql files executed by load_all.sql will inherit the `SET DEFINE OFF` variable, and if this is or is not client dependent?**

Comment: By the way, it's a good idea to give PL/SQL source code files a different extension from SQL scripts, especially when working with PL/SQL Developer as it uses the extension the determine which type of window to open it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the files called by the parent script will inherit the `SET DEFINE OFF`

Comment: And its not client dependent? We should expect this same functionality across all clients ( sqlplus, ant, sql developer, pl/sql developer, etc )?

Comment: Correct. It will maintain that setting for the remainder of the session or unless it is changed back to ON.  Your best bet is to fix the comments that are causing errors.

Comment: Even in your example code, if `SET DEFINE OFF` is specified in `financial_aid.sql` or `other_file.sql`, the setting will still be set when `other_file2.sql` is running.